# Lower limit value of electric force

Tags: electrostatics, coulombs-law

What is the lower limit value to the electric force between two charges separated by a fixed distance?

Comment: if you asking what is force between 2 charges separated by infinite distance, I may refer you to see the [inverse square law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law)

Comment: Are you asking how low the force can get if you reduce the charges? If so see Mohammad's answer.

Comment: Maybe he thinks of something like the minimal value in the sense of a *quant of force*, just like we can say that energy quant is $h\nu$.

Comment: @JohnRennie where is it?

Comment: @user541396 [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/177252/1325). I think the user name has changed since I posted my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

If the charges are kept at a fixed distance R, the force will be given by:

$$ F = \frac{kQ_1Q_2}{r^2} $$

The smallest possible charge that can exist freely is that of an electron or proton which is numerically equal to $1.6 \times 10^{-19}$ coulomb, put the values in the equation and you get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no range of electric force values, F = k*q/r^2 It will be fixed unless you having a mechanism that makes the charges to vary as required.

Answer (score 0):

The formula for electric force is given by $F = k \dfrac{q_1q_2}{r^2}$

Where $q_1$ and $q_2$ are the charges, and $r$ is the distance. Therefore, there is no lower limit. It is always given by this formula.

Comment: Well charge is always quantized. So no. Charge is always in integral multiple of charge of electron.